# My games keep freezing

Tags: xbox-one

I bought a game new. It kept freezing, so I took it back for another copy but that one didn't work either.

So I took the second copy of the game back again and they finally gave me my money back. I bought another game (Sniper Elite 3) and I also bought a one year warranty. After it finished installing, I opened the game for the first time and it said loading data. It sat on a loading screen for about an hour. It didn't freeze - it was just loading.

What's causing two different games to freeze? How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it sounds like there's a problem with your xbox-one.

Comment: 5pike is probably right, it does sound like a console issue. Im not sure what might be the cause of the issue, what about games that you already owned? Do they still work? How about digital games, are they resulting the same? I would certainly try a game you previously played and see what happens. It sounds like a hardware/firmware issue if it is not to one particular game, you may have to think about making use of your warranty (hopefully you are still in it!)

Comment: Try doing a full reboot to clear the cache. Hold the power button down for several seconds. The console should then beep and turn off. Turn it on again should take a couple of minutes. Nb unplugging it does not have same effect.

Comment: Doing this has resolved similar problems for me with other games where the console seemed to just freeze at a certain point and not progress but was still responsive to for example going through menus.

Comment: Sounds to me like your second copy was working fine, you just didn't wait for it to be fully installed.  The "Ready to Start" notification can be misleading as for many games it really means "You can now look at a loading screen in this game while the rest of it is installed."  And yes I did notice you say "about an hour," installing can be a very lengthy process.